# Incomplete response after httpget on 3g Android

Tags: android, httpclient, http-get, 3g

in my Android application i am trying to get a website using the httpclient and the httpget.
it is working fine on the emulator and on my HTC Desire HD. 
but when i disconnect from wifi and try to get te webpage on the 3G network the response is sometimes incomplete. 
i am using the following code to get the webpage:

```
public String htmlBody (String strURI)
{
String strBody = "";
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpclient.getParams(), false);
try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(strURI);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        strBody = Functions.convertStreamToString(entity.getContent());
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

return strBody;
}
```

is there a way to make sure that the response is complete? or resume the httpget when the response is incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem with you recently. After a few experiments, I guess I found the answer:
Android won't read complete response with a single InputStream#read() call in 3G network.
The following code may work:

```
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
int length = 0;
while (true) {
    int ret = in.read(buffer, length, buffer.length - length);
    if (ret == -1) break;
    length += ret;
}
```

Comment: here, what is buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: Make your website put like a special character at the end of the response and then check if that character exists. If its there you ll know u got the full response, if its not then resend the request or something!

Comment: I have tried to re-execute the httpget until i get the complete website. It wil get a complete response after a few attemps but sometimes it takes 10 to 30 attemps. So it is not really workable.

Comment: @user686404 Why does it not get the full response? Thats weird! If an exception is not thrown(i.e. a socket timeout) then it should get the whole response I think!

Comment: There are no exceptions thrown, but just to make sure i will re-check for exceptions tomorrow.

Comment: there are no exeptions thrown when the response is incomplete.

Comment: @user686404 Ok! It shouldn't make a difference but heres how I do it!

Try instead of: `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        strBody = Functions.convertStreamToString(entity.getContent());` 

Try having: `strBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`

Tell us also what an incomplete response looks like!

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. The HTML in the response is just incompleet. the lenght of the incompleet response is always of a different lenght. the html is cut of in the middle of an html-tag or in a word.

Comment: the apache http client built into Android is somewhat buggy. It is not the latest version of apache http client. For example, by apache httpclient 4.2, EntityUtils.consume() method is present again and HttpEntity.consume() method is deprecated.